# Two columns are not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have green and blue div, and I want to divide it in to two. I already tried to use  but it isn't working. Can someone help me?

This is my code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6" style="background: #008080;">
                <form role="form" method="post" action="<?=base_url()?>login/login_submit">
                    <h2>Please Sign In</h2>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="username" id="email" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Username">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <span class="button-checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" id="remember_me" checked="checked" class="hidden">
                        <a class="btn" data-color="info">Stay Signed In</a>
                        <a href="<?=base_url()?>login/forgotpassword" class="btn btn-link pull-right">Forgot Password?</a>
                    </span>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" value="Sign In">
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6" style="background: #009926">
                <p>Hello World!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my output so far:
https://prnt.sc/h52st4

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean when you say "divide it in to two?"

Comment: divide by 2 horizontally or vertically, please specify

Comment: This is a bootstrap question so i removed html as its extraneous

Comment: If you have used bootstrap classes, then the output is not same which you have shared.

Please be more specific, and create one jsfiddle or jsbin for clear reference

Comment: @RainLai Sorry, it's vertically. By the way, it's already fixed. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add classes for different resolutions of screen. Add these classes with your col-lg-6 class. For Example

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="background: #009926">
        <p>Hello World!</p>
    </div>
```

Your whole code will look like this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="background: #008080;">
        <form role="form" method="post" action="<?=base_url()?>login/login_submit">
            <h2>Please Sign In</h2>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="username" id="email" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <span class="button-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" id="remember_me" checked="checked" class="hidden">
                <a class="btn" data-color="info">Stay Signed In</a>
                <a href="<?=base_url()?>login/forgotpassword" class="btn btn-link pull-right">Forgot Password?</a>
            </span>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" value="Sign In">
                </div>
            </div>  
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="background: #009926">
        <p>Hello World!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also include bootstrap css to see the result.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
```

Comment: It works! Thank you very much Sir! Really appreciate. :)